# Why do i get "Exception:" when i receive the exception message in dart?

Tags: http, flutter, exception

Hi I am new to the dart and flutter framework.

I am throwing error like below from my service class where i am calling the API.

```
if(res["status"]!=200) throw new Exception("Invalid User");
```

and receiving in presenter class like below and printing

```
.catchError((Object error){
      print(error);

});
```

I am expecting the result as "Invalid User", but am getting with additional word like "Exception: Invalid User". Can you please explain me why this additional word 'Exception' is coming? and how can i get only the string which i am passing.

Comment: extension FormattedMessage on Exception {
  String get message {
    // Define a regular expression to match the pattern "Exception: message"
    RegExp regex = RegExp(r'^.*Exception: (.+)$');
    // Try to match the regular expression with the exception message
    Match? match = regex.firstMatch(toString());
    // If a match is found, return only the message part, otherwise return the entire exception string
    return match != null ? match.group(1)! : toString();
  }
}


This will also works for: FormatException, HttpException, etc..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Surprisingly that's how written in exception toString code.

```
 String toString() {
    if (message == null) return "Exception";
    return "Exception: $message";  // your message will be appended after exception. 
  }
```

If you want to avoid this then you have to create custom exception like below:

```
class HttpException implements Exception {
  final String message;

  HttpException(this.message);  // Pass your message in constructor. 

  @override
  String toString() {
    return message;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an extension function in dart as

```
extension FormattedMessage on Exception {
  String get getMessage {
    if (toString().startsWith("Exception: ")) {
      return toString().substring(11);
    }else {
      return toString();
    }
  }
}
```

After that you can simply call

```
exception.getMessage;
```

to get your extension message without having to implement the Extension class or show the user how the exception is being substring.

Answer (score 2):

Quick solution:

```
.catchError((error){
  print(
    error.toString().substring(11)
  );
});
```

You cut the first 11 message chars, that is, "Exception: ".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `message` property of the `Exception object`

```
.catchError((error){
  print(error.message);

});
```

This should output `Invalid User`

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: From 2.17.1, Surprisingly, there is no way to invoke `.message` from catching Exception instance. We have only `.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use ErrorDescription

```
throw ErrorDescription(response['error']);
```

It still acts as an error but you don't get the "Exception" infront of the error